# Getting an authoritative user id / email in GAE federated login

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, federated-identity

When performing authentication using the OpenID federated login on GAE, my user object has the following properties:

```
Nickname: http://wordfaire.com/openid?id=103539105724544727060
email: sudhir.j@wordfaire.com
```

From the docs,

> **email()**
>
> Returns the email address of
> the user. If you use OpenID, you
> should not rely on this email address
> to be correct. Applications should use
> nickname for displayable names.

Obviously, this advice isn't working out very well. So how then can I get an authoritative email handle to associate with a particular OpenID provided by any Google Apps or other domain? I really need the email ID because things like invitations and sharing / access control all function via email ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a valid email for OpenID users, ask the user to supply one the first time they log in, and store it yourself along with their user object.

Since anyone can create an OpenID provider, it's not safe to assume that the provider has already gathered a valid address.

Comment: I'm only accepting domains running Google Apps, so that isn't a problem. Do you know if logins using Google Apps are guaranteed to return an email id?

Comment: I believe so, but if you only want to accept Google credentials, why use Open ID at all?

Comment: That's a really good point, actually. Single sign on integration with Google Apps would be one reason...

Comment: The default Accounts API supports Google Apps credentials as well as standard gmail credentials. You don't need OpenID if you only want to support these two options.

Comment: Come to think of it, you're quite right. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Actually, no. I just checked appspot.com and it doesn't work that way. Take a look at the app creation screen and the auth options there.

Comment: @Sudhir If your Apps users have upgraded their accounts, it does work that way - just select the standard authentication option, and Apps users with upgraded accounts will be able to log in like everyone else.

Comment: Ah, okay. Great, do you guys have any numbers on the percentage of Apps users who've upgraded? I'd rather not cut out a huge portion of my target market simply because the admins didn't upgrade.

Comment: @Nick - Do upgraded Apps accounts also provide a guaranteed user_id field?

Comment: @Sudhir All users who can log in will have a unique user_id field - that's the point of having one!